# What causes this Java error in OpenSplice?

Tags: java, fatal-error, jvm-hotspot, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I'm using OpenSplice version 6.4 to develop an application with two sites in different networks. When I try to collect data from an external node, I got this error:

```
[thread 140436299368192 also had an error]#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb9df606479, pid=32216, tid=0x00007fb9dfb88700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libdcpssaj.so+0x2f479]  saj_dataReaderListenerOnDataAvailable+0x39
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/server/core or core.32216
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/server/hs_err_pid32216.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I'm using Java version 1.8.0_181 and Ubuntu server 16.04. Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: What's in the `/home/server/hs_err_pid32216.log` file?

Answer (score 0):

@Alex8752, there might be different things here like JVM defect, lack of resources (OOM-like issues). In order to answer this question, it would be good if you post the

- application startup arguments with JVM keys
- thread dump (few per seconds from launch till before application fails)